# Loop through rows and seperate out each "visit"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with Visits, Completed Applications, and Approvals with each row as a zipcode, and I'm trying to turn the table into a table in which each row is a Visit. Since I'm in Excel, I'm trying to write a macro in VBA to do this, but it's giving me slight inaccuracies. Here is my table:

```
Zip     Visits Applications   Approvals
75229   3      2              1

                |
                |
                v

Zip     Visits          Applications    Approvals
75229   1               0               0
75229   1               1               0
75229   1               1               1
```

And here is my macro:

```
Sub TestMacro1()

Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim PrintCell As Range


For n = 0 To 5000
    Set StartCell = Range("A2").Offset(n, 0)
    Set PrintCell = Range("F10000").End(xlUp)



    For i = 1 To StartCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        PrintCell.Offset(i, 0) = StartCell.Value
        PrintCell.Offset(i, 1) = 1

        If i <= StartCell.Offset(0, 2).Value Then
             PrintCell.Offset(i, 2) = 1
        Else
            PrintCell.Offset(i, 2) = 0
        End If
        If i <= StartCell.Offset(0, 3).Value Then
            PrintCell.Offset(i, 3) = 1
        Else
            PrintCell.Offset(i, 3) = 0
        End If


    Next i

Next n

End Sub
```

There are 4244 total Visits, 3508 rows, 815 Completed Applications, and 58 Approvals, but when I run my macro I get 4244 Visits, 770 Completed Applications, and 55 Approvals. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Might the number of applications or approvals ever exceed the number of visits? This is one explanation for the discrepancy

Comment: @DyRuss it does indeed, 39 times there are more Completed Apps than there are Visits, many thanks for your help

Comment: @Mike check out my code below in answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requires you to have to sheets (you can name them whatever you want and fix code accordingly)  Edit: This code finds the averages per visit (and the remainder after that) and distributes them among the cells evenly per your example.  Tested working!

```
Sub TestMacro1()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurRow As Long
Dim DestRow As Long
Dim ChkRow As Long
Dim CurWS As Worksheet
Dim DestWS As Worksheet
Dim Visits As Integer
Dim Apps As Integer
Dim Approvals As Integer
Dim AvgApps As Integer
Dim AvgApprovals As Integer
Dim Zip As String
Dim AppsRemain As Integer
Dim ApprovalsRemain As Integer

Set CurWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
Set DestWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DestTest")

LastRow = CurWS.Range("A" & CurWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
    Zip = CurWS.Cells(CurRow, 1).Value 'Assumes Zip is in Column A (1)
    Visits = CurWS.Cells(CurRow, 2).Value 'Assumes Visits is in Col B (2)
    Apps = CurWS.Cells(CurRow, 3).Value 'Assumes Apps is in Col C (3)
    Approvals = CurWS.Cells(CurRow, 4).Value 'Assumes Approvals is in Col D (4)
    AvgApps = Apps \ Visits
    AvgApprovals = Approvals \ Visits
    AppsRemain = Apps Mod Visits
    ApprovalsRemain = Approvals Mod Visits
        DestRow = DestWS.Range("A" & DestWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        For ChkRow = Visits To 1 Step -1
            DestWS.Cells(DestRow + ChkRow - 1, 1).Value = Zip 'Assumes Zip is in Column A (1)
            DestWS.Cells(DestRow + ChkRow - 1, 2).Value = 1 'Assumes Visits is in Col B (2)
            If AppsRemain > 0 Then
                DestWS.Cells(DestRow + ChkRow - 1, 3).Value = AvgApps + 1 'Assumes Apps is in Col C (3)
                AppsRemain = AppsRemain - 1
                Else
                DestWS.Cells(DestRow + ChkRow - 1, 3).Value = AvgApps 'Assumes Apps is in Col C (3)
            End If
            If ApprovalsRemain > 0 Then
                DestWS.Cells(DestRow + ChkRow - 1, 4).Value = AvgApprovals + 1 'Assumes Approvals is in Col D (4)
                ApprovalsRemain = ApprovalsRemain - 1
                Else
                DestWS.Cells(DestRow + ChkRow - 1, 4).Value = AvgApprovals 'Assumes Approvals is in Col D (4)
            End If
        Next ChkRow
Next CurRow

End Sub
```